# How can I report on who has viewed a file in an Office 365 SharePoint library?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-office-365

I want to store a bunch of policies in a SharePoint library (Office 365) and want to be able to report on all users who have viewed the document.

I could do it like this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US (using auditing on the site) but it seems like overkill. I just need to report on each distinct user who has viewed each document, not every time they have accessed it.

Can this be done "out of the box" or if not is there a (O365 friendly) plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable audit logs for this. This can be enabled at site collection level.

Go to site settings--> Site collection administration-->Site collection audit settings-->Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing item properties. You can take a look at the following article.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA102039795.aspx

Comment: *sigh* above answer is not great but appreciate the effort. The link you provided is information for SharePoint 2010 This is currently not a feature available in SharePoint Online (O365) - only On-Premise Here is a better reference link
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2?CorrelationId=03c99a70-a899-433a-a19c-c312967a8087&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 365 audit logging. Not for the site collection but in the 365 admin compliance center. It will show all activitites including opened, *and other things that the original author of this answer probably meant to include*

Comment: Proofread your answers for both typos and that you finished your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to go a little further and get a positive acknowledgement that documents have been read with audit reports. Take at look at [Read and Understood for SharePoint](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-gb/product/office/WA200002742) on Microsoft AppSource